# What is an example of "where" in an adverb clause?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, subordinate-clauses

All the sentences I can think of are anything but an adverb clause. For example:

"*Where I'm going* is none of your business." (A noun clause as the subject)

"No one knows *where he is*." (A noun clause as the object)

"It's interesting *where these things have come from*." (A noun clause as an adjective complement)

"This is *where I want to be*." (A noun clause as a subject complement)

"This is the park *where we first met*." (An adjective clause)

"She was surprised by *where I had gotten the magazine*." (A noun clause as the object of the preposition)

Can you please make an example of an adverb clause with "where"?

Thank you

Comment: [Here,](https://englishsentences.com/adverb-clause/) the adverb clauses are underlined: ***Wherever they have carrots**, you will find the rabbit.* I can't do underlining in a comment, but I *can* point out that there's nothing wrong with using ***where*** instead of ***wherever*** in that example (which would *still* be an "adverb clause", for whatever use that classification might be).

Comment: 'Put the remote where I told you to.'

Comment: *I'm going where the weather suits my clothes.*

Comment: The problem with the examples given in FF's link is that they are not clauses but PPs. For example, "wherever they have carrots" has no adverb ("wherever" is a preposition) and the PP functions as an adjunct of place, though many learners use the term 'adverbial' for 'adjunct'.

Comment: The examples are all headless relatives, or embedded questions; in either case, certainly noun clauses. But locative noun clauses, which like all nouns can appear as objects of prepositions. The prepositions don't have much meaning, and they often disappear or reappear in constructions, like the Dative alternation: _She gave the book to him/She gave him the book_. If you want a non-noun clause, there are non-restrictive relatives (adjective clauses) like _She went to Brisbane, where she found love,_ and adverbial clauses like _Where I was seated, I couldn't hear very well , so I moved_.

Answer (score 4):

> [1] [*Where I'm going*] *is none of your business*.
>
> [2] *No one knows* [*where he is*].
>
> [3] *It's interesting* [*where these things have come from*].
>
> [4] *This is* [*where I want to be*].
>
> [5] *This is the park* [*where we first met*].
>
> [6] *She was surprised by* [*where I had gotten the magazine*].

The bracketed expressions in [1] [2] and [6] are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions) functioning respectively as subject, complement of "know", and complement of "by".

[3] is an extrapostion construction in which the subordinate clause is an extraposed subject. The basic non-extraposed equivalent is "Where these things have come from is interesting", where the subordinate clause is an interrogative.

[4] is a fused relative construction in which "where I want to be" is a noun phrase as subjective predicative complement of "be".

[5] is a relative clause modifying "park".

Note that in [5] "where" functions as an adjunct (your adverbial) of place in the relative clause, though it's a PP, not a clause.

Incidentally, I would strongly recommend dropping the term 'noun clause'. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.